# Spring Integration FTP Java DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to transfer remote files from an FTP repo to a local repo. At the moment it works in terms of the initial transfer and if the local file is deleted but I would like it to pick up on remote file changes from the last modified timestamp. I have read around trying to create a custom filter but can't find much information on doing this via Java DSL.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpInboundFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s -> s
                    .ftp(this.ftpSessionFactory())
                            .preserveTimestamp(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(ftpData.getRemoteDirectory())
                            .localDirectory(new File(ftpData.getLocalDirectory())),
                    e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter").autoStartup(true))
            .channel(MessageChannels.publishSubscribe())
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed only recently: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4232.

Meanwhile you don't have choice unless delete local files after processing.

You have to use `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` any way, because of: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4115.

There is nothing from Java DSL perspective.

**UPDATE**

> can you point me towards how to delete local files via Java DSL

The `FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` produces a message already for local file as a payload. In addition there are some headers like:

```
.setHeader(FileHeaders.RELATIVE_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath()
                        .replaceFirst(Matcher.quoteReplacement(this.directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator),
                                ""))
.setHeader(FileHeaders.FILENAME, file.getName())
.setHeader(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, file)
```

When you're done with the file downstream already you can delete it via regular `File.delete()` operation. That can be done for example using `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`:

```
@Bean
public Advice deleteFileAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("headers[file_originalFile].delete()");
    return advice;
}

...
.<String>handle((p, h) -> ..., e -> e.advice(deleteFileAdvice()))
```

Comment: So, to overcome this I would have to delete my local files before running the FTP service to therefore get the most recent remote files? Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. And make it working permanent you have to delete local files after downstream processing.

Comment: Great thanks, can you point me towards how to delete local files via Java DSL and if not via Java Config?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.